# Javascript: closures? eventlistener won't add

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures, event-listener

I seem to have a problem, and I suspect it's a problem with closures. I got 3 buttons, and when I run this code only the last button gets an eventlistener. This is why I suspect a closures problem. I tried all sorts of things as create other functions but the didn't help me. In the function addListeners i have 3 console.logs with information and they display the RIGHT information. So in addeventlisteners I have the right DIV, with the right information but it doesn't add a listener. Could anyone help me out here? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
function CheckAiringShows(slug,lastwatched,Length) {
var nmb = lastwatched.number;
var nxnmb = nmb +1;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/calendars/all/shows/"+strDate+"/30",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "trakt-api-version": "2",
        "trakt-api-key": "a16246673f04042fca0fbc80eddd2b8b742524f62deaf11a6d0daf97f053005f"
    },
    success : function(response)
    {
        response.forEach(function (object, index) {
            if(slug == object.show.ids.slug){
                var airdate = new Date(object.first_aired).format("dddd, mmmm dS 'at' HH:MM:ss");

                var nextnumber = "s"+object.episode.season+"e"+object.episode.number;
                document.getElementsByClassName("airingshow")[0].innerHTML += "<label for='test'>"+object.show.title+": "+nextnumber+" "+airdate+"</label><input type='submit' class='calendar' id='"+object.episode.ids.trakt+"' value='Add to calendar!'/>";

                var calend = document.getElementById(object.episode.ids.trakt);
                addListeners(calend,object,Length);
            }
        });

    }
});
}
function addListeners(item,object,length){
    console.log(item);
    console.log(object);
    console.log(length);
          // this line didn't work out at all, nothing got an eventlistener this way.
          // return function(){item.addEventListener('click', function(){makeApiCall(object,length)})};
    item.addEventListener('click', function(){makeApiCall(object,length)});
}
```

Comment: This question is a mess... can you edit it so that you don't need `EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT` for the question to make sense? your edits should flow with the question such that you don't need to add `EDIT` headers. Additionally, the `SOLVED` section doesn't belong in the question, that belongs in an answer with an explanation of what was wrong, and how it was fixed.

Comment: Okay sorry, i just deleted all the edits. I thought it could be handy for people having likewise problems.

Comment: Thanks, those of us that would like to see edits can do so through the revision history. Click o. The date on the "edited by" section to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are replacing the `innerHTML` in every iteration, effectively destroying previously created DOM elements and replacing them.

Here's a few solutions:

- First generate the entire HTML, then change the `innerHTML` and attach handlers.
- Attach a single handler on the container and handle bubbling events on the children you want (event delegation).
- Construct the DOM using the DOM API (e.g. `document.createElement(...)`, `container.appendChild(...)`).

Event delegation is usually more simple if the content of a container is dynamic, because you do not have to worry about adding handlers on newly added elements.

```js
$('#dynamic-container')
  .on('click', 'button', function () {
    alert('You clicked on a button!'); 
  })
  //cliking dynamically added button will also work
  .append('<button>dynamic button</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic-container">
  <button>static button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but I still seem to have the same problem. It only works on the last one. I editted my question so you can see my new code with explanation.

Comment: @Runey This approach doesn't add a listener to a specific child element, so it's not possible that it only works for the latest one if you've implemented it correctly. Instead of calling addListeners just try to call this once `$('.airingshow').on('click', 'input.calendar', function (e) { alert('clicked');  });` You also need to realize that your input is a `submit` input, therefore the form will get submitted and the page will refresh if you do not prevent the default form submission behavior with `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: that didn't work well, if i clicked any button all three worked, because airinghshow was a parent div. Now i took a div inside those and it seems to work in the sense that when i load my page every button activates on load and not on click.
document.getElementsByClassName("airingshow")[0].innerHTML += "<div class='singleshows' id='"+object.episode.ids.trakt+"'><label>"+object.show.title+": "+nextnumber+" "+airdate+"</label><input type='submit' class='calendar'  value='Add to calendar!'/></div>";
                    $('.singleshows').on('click', 'input.calendar', makeApiCall(object,Length));

Comment: It seems that it was my fault for not doing (function(e){makeapicall}
I did that now but now i always get the same value sent, the value of the last one. So i got the value problem again

Comment: It makes sense though, I always add one click handler to ALL singleshows classes, i need every singleshows class to have a different click handler. So i should use an ID?

Comment: i updated my question again, with new code and a picture of my console.log

Comment: @Runey Have you read my answer? You are still doing the same mistake that I'm describing. By doing `document.getElementsByClassName("airingshow")[0].innerHTML += ` in every iteration of the loop you are destroying and recreating all DOM elements contained within that container. Therefore you lose all listeners except the last one.

Comment: Yes i have, please read my second edit there i do not do that ;)

Comment: @Runey Yes you do... `response.forEach(function (object, index) {` that's a loop and the line of code I mentioned is within the loop's body. Therefore, it runs on every iteration ;)

Comment: Oh... i see what you mean now. The problem is that i use a function on my click, and in that function i need the values from that loop..

Comment: Okay i can't quite follow, the line of code you mentioned would work on the entire class right? so if i found some way to get those values out of the loop and in the one line you mentioned, then i still wouldn't be able to know what button I pressed and what values i need to use right? Also i don't destroy the innerhtml but add onto the innerhtml since I use += is what i thought :/

Comment: @Runey `innerHTML += html` is the same as `innerHTML = innerHTML + html`. To avoid destroying the DOM you need to use the DOM API like I mentioned in my answer. `var $container = $('.airingshow'); var $newButton = $('<button>some button</button>'); $container.append($newButton);`

Comment: Okay, I tried something else. It seems that I still don't understand completely what you mean though.  i don't use innerHTML += ... anymore. Could you by any chance provide me of a working example code with my code? I do not understand how i should add the onclick with the object & length that i get in the .forEach loop. If i do as you say and get it out of the loop i can't assign those values. Look at my third edit, i used the DOM API now but do not know where to add my onclick event.

Comment: @Runey Your code is almost correct (not necessarily efficient, but it works). Your problem is that you used event delegation when you shouldn't... basically `$newInput.on('click', 'button', function () {` should be `$newInput.on('click', function () {` or `$newInput.click(function () {`

Comment: well I just seem to have fixed it myself though, I went over your answer once more and decided to try out even delegation (now I read that i shouldn't have) What i do is on window i add a load eventlistener that adds a listener to the whole package, then i check which input is clicked and i get its ID (the ID is an encoded array with the object & length) and i use that to execute the function. This might be very inefficient too but it works! :D thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @Runey Event delegation is great and it's the way I would have done it. I was just saying that in your edit the way you were trying to apply it was incorrect because you treated the input element itself as the container. I'm glad it worked!